# Spring mvc redis cache template configuration error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redis

i have a local Redis server running  with `127.0.0.1:6379`

when iam creating the template for the configuration it is not creating the template

```
@Configuration
public class AWSRedisCacheConfig {

        @Bean
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
            PropObjectLoader propObjectLoader = new PropObjectLoader();
            RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(propObjectLoader.getPropertyValue("elastic.redis.hostname"),Integer.parseInt(propObjectLoader.getPropertyValue("elastic.redis.port")));
            return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
        }

        @Bean(name = {"redisTemplate"})
        public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
            PropObjectLoader propObjectLoader = new PropObjectLoader();
            RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(propObjectLoader.getPropertyValue("elastic.redis.hostname"),Integer.parseInt(propObjectLoader.getPropertyValue("elastic.redis.port")));
            RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
            redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration));
            return redisTemplate;
        }
}
```

i have created the a Redis Template and trying to create a template object but it not happening in **spring mvc4.5**

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing?

Comment: @VinayAvasthi  -- when iam using the put method for creating a template it is not creating.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code that is calling put method.

Comment: `ElastiCacheDTO cacheDto = new ElastiCacheDTO("","aa",ArrayList.class);
  ElasticCacheUtils<List<OptionListDTO>> cacheUtils = new ElasticCacheUtils<List<OptionListDTO>>();
  optionList=  cacheUtils.get(cacheDto);`

Comment: @VinayAvasthi i have given the code in above comment